# How to remove loading product images from cache in magento?

Tags: image, magento, product

Due to some problems product images in cache folder turned empty (file is there but empty).Magneto loads product images from cache folder only.
For example: http://example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/54/small_image/295x295/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/br7462vi_1.png 
here  br7462vi_1.png  turned empty.(0 bytes).

but http://example.com/media/catalog/product/b/r/br7462vi_1.png works fine.

How can I stop magento loading product images from cache?

Comment: Why not just delete the cache?

Comment: you mean, delete product/cache folder from server?

Comment: There seems to be a way to do it in the GUI. Te following is from the Enterprise Edition but it seems likely the Open Source edition has a button for it, as well. http://merch.docs.magento.com/ee_docs/content/system-operations/cache-clear.html

Answer (score 2):

No need to worry. Simply Login to admin panel.

Goto Admin ->System ->Cache management *click* on **Flush Catalog Images Cache**

And also flush all magento cache.

Now all image urls should work.

If you have still problem then just give 777 permission on **media/catalog/product** directory.

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this from list.phtml and all your custome template where you want to load from main media folder

```
<img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                 src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(236,193); ?>"
                 alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

With This Code:

```
<img width="236" height="193" id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                 src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $_product->getSmallImage()); ?>"
                 alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

it only for grid mode you can change for list mode also and product details page medai.pthml file only change on this file src tag src=`"<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $_product->getSmallImage()); ?>"`

Reference: [How to remove the cache url for product images in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882986/how-to-remove-the-cache-url-for-product-images-in-magento)